# CSS: Confused about behavior of the > selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I thought the > selector only selects direct children of an element (excluding inherited properties) but the following example has me confused:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>

    <li>Item 2
        <ol>Subitem 2
            <li>Subitem 2A</li>
            <li>Subitem 2B</li>
        </ol>
    </li>

    <li>Item 3
        <li>Subitem 3a
            <li>Subitem 3aa
                <ol>Subitem 3aaa
                    <li>Subitem 3aaaa
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </li>
    </li>

    <ol>Item 4</ol>
</ul>

ul>li {
    color: green;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:20px;
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

So I try this out and this is what I see on Chrome "Version 30.0.1599.101 m":
[image]

I tried to work out how the rules were being applied but I don't understand it completely:

Item 1,2,3:
Get all the styles because they are direct children of the ul and are li

Item 4:
Doesn’t get any styles because it is not an li

Subitem 2-2B:
Get the inherited color and font styles, but don’t get the border styles. Is this because they are not direct children or because they are not li?

Subitem 3a and 3aa:
Get all the styles- why? They are not direct child of the ul. Its looks like the > selector hits all child items of the same type until they are interrupted by an item of a different type- is this correct?

Subitem 3aaa and 3aaaa:
Don’t get border style, but still get inherited color and font styles. Is this because they are children of an li which does have those styles? Why is this?

Just trying to wrap my head around this behavior.

Comment: You're having problems because your code is invalid. You cannot have an `<li>` inside an `<li>` without first having either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` as its immediate parent. The browser is assuming you meant to put one in, and is putting it in for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest `<li>` within `<li>` without starting another `<ul>`. The browser is closing the `<li>` for you automatically.

Comment: `<li>` has optional close tag.  The browser isn't inserting `<ul>`, it's inserting `</li>`.

Answer (score 1):

the `>` means any element that is direct child of previous element(s).

so....

`ul li` means that any li that is inside ul should be selected.

`ul>li` means any li that is direct children, like `<ul> <li>...` & not like `<ul> <li> <p> <li> this last li wont get the styles...`

it was confusing at first but became clear very quickly.

but in your case since you are not putting ul or ol before starting another li. browser adds one. And that makes the indirect li a child of ul and thus it gets selected too.

Answer (score 1):

`<li>` has optional close tags, so if the browser sees another `<li>` before a correpsonding `</li>`, it implicitly inserts a close for the previous tag.  You can verify this using the DOM inspector in your browser's developer tools.  This means that Item 3's "subitems" are actually siblings to Item 3.

[image: DOM view]

- [Relevant WHATWG spec showing optional close tag](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)
- [W3 spec showing optional close tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the DOM inspector. Looking at it I can clearly see how the browser closed those <li> tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have an open li tag. Say if you were to close the Item 3 with a `</li>` right after Item 3 , instead of leaving it open. Then the ol's would not turn green. But b.c they are open, the ol is part of a li.

```
<li>Item 3
        <li>Subitem 3a
            <li>Subitem 3aa
                <ol>Subitem 3aaa
                    <li>Subitem 3aaaa
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pity the submitted html was badly formed because this only makes things more confusing. However, even if well formed, all the nested lis will still be color green but they won't have borders.

**Why?**

Because of inheritance - color, font-size and font-style are all inherited properties - border isn't.

This shows the limitation of the direct child selector - you can't use it with properties that inherit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: There is no question - it's a statement: "CSS: Confused about behaviour of > selector". The confusion is definitely to do with inheritance and how the direct child selector cannot cope with it. The badly formatted html is a red herring. Once this is fixed the inheritance confusion will still be there.